# How can I write this with Nest or Fold?

Tags: recursion, functional-style

```
a[1] = Sqrt[s[0]^2 + s[0] + 1] /. s[0] -> 0
a[2] = Sqrt[s[1]^2 + s[1] + 1] /. s[1] -> a[1]
a[3] = Sqrt[s[2]^2 + s[2] + 1] /. s[2] -> a[1] + a[2]
a[4] = Sqrt[s[3]^2 + s[3] + 1] /. s[3] -> a[1] + a[2] + a[3]


f = Sqrt[#^2 + # + 1] &;
f[1]
f[1 + %]
f[1 + f[1] + %]
f[1 + f[1] + f[1 + f[1]] + %]
f[1 + f[1] + f[1 + f[1]] + f[1 + f[1] + f[1 + f[1]]] + %]
```

I have tried the following, but it didn't work well:

```
  Rest@FoldList[f[+##] &, 0, Table[1, 5]]
```

> ```
> {
>   f[1], 
>   f[1 + f[1]], 
>   f[1 + f[1 + f[1]]], 
>   f[1 + f[1 + f[1 + f[1]]]], 
>   f[1 + f[1 + f[1 + f[1 + f[1]]]]]
> }
> ```

Comment: Do you mean `NestList[f[1 + #] &, 0, 5]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NestList[# + Sqrt[#^2 + # + 1] &, 0, 4] // Differences // Column
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
NestList[f[## & @@ # + #] &, f[1], 3]
```

> ```
> {
>    f[1], 
>    f[1 + f[1]], 
>    f[1 + f[1] + f[1 + f[1]]], 
>    f[1 + f[1] + f[1 + f[1]] + f[1 + f[1] + f[1 + f[1]]]]
> }
> ```

alternatively (but we have to start with `f[1+f[1]]`:

```
NestList[Insert[#, #, {1, -1}] &, f[1 + f[1]], 2]
```

> ```
> {
>  f[1 + f[1]], 
>  f[1 + f[1] + f[1 + f[1]]], 
>  f[1 + f[1] + f[1 + f[1]] + f[1 + f[1] + f[1 + f[1]]]]
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

This may not be ideal or the most elegant, but perhaps it will work or help.

Define (note that `int` can be whatever range you want):

```
In[3]:= a[0] = 0;
int = Range[4];
```

Create a list of symbols for your LHS:

```
In[3]:= lhs = a[#] & /@ int

Out[3]= {a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]}
```

This gives us your RHS's, primarily just mapping a `expr /. rule` expression across the iterators `{1,2,3,4}`:

```
In[4]:= vals = (Sqrt[s[# - 1]^2 + s[# - 1] + 1] /. 
     s[# - 1] -> FoldList[#1 + a[#2] &, int - 1][[#]]) & /@ int

Out[4]= {1, Sqrt[1 + a[1] + a[1]^2], Sqrt[
 1 + a[1] + a[2] + (a[1] + a[2])^2], Sqrt[
 1 + a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + (a[1] + a[2] + a[3])^2]}
```

And you can thread Set across them to get your end result:

```
In[5]:= Thread@Set[Evaluate[lhs], vals]

Out[5]= {1, Sqrt[3], Sqrt[2 + Sqrt[3] + (1 + Sqrt[3])^2], Sqrt[
 2 + Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[
  2 + Sqrt[3] + (1 + Sqrt[3])^2] + (1 + Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[
    2 + Sqrt[3] + (1 + Sqrt[3])^2])^2]}
```

To verify this...

```
In[6]:= {a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]}

Out[6]= {1, Sqrt[3], Sqrt[2 + Sqrt[3] + (1 + Sqrt[3])^2], Sqrt[
 2 + Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[
  2 + Sqrt[3] + (1 + Sqrt[3])^2] + (1 + Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[
    2 + Sqrt[3] + (1 + Sqrt[3])^2])^2]}
```

Like I said, you can let `int` be as high as you want to define as many values of `a[n]` are necessary. This isn't recursive, but it would work. Hoping someone can provide a better solution :)

Comment: Thank you, but it's not I'm looking for.

Comment: @mathe Edited it based on your edits :)